# All Jquery toggles have no animation when using Bootsrap?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am building a website with Django and Bootsrap. I am writing some custom JS to show/hide nodes in an organization tree. I have noticed however, that any element I call using jquery's .toggle on is shown/hidden immediately, regardless of what I set the animation duration parameter to `.toggle(1000)` for example.
[GIF showing the issue](https://gyazo.com/d8017f8ce8a700dbddaf6332b05c1c30)

Has anyone else had this problem with Bootsrap or Django? Or is my code bad? I am attaching a snippet of the actual JS function and the same rendered HTML that strangely works in the snippet but not on my site. For reference I am using jquery 3.3.1 and Bootstrap 4.1.1

```html
<ul>
                
                    <li class="tree-menu">

                        Root Organization-1
                        
                            <ul class="children">
                                
                    <li class="tree-menu">

                        Org1-2
                        
                    </li>
                
                    <li class="tree-menu">

                        parent3-3
                        
                            <ul class="children" style="">
                                
                    <li class="tree-menu">

                        child3a1-4
                        
                            <ul class="children" style="">
                                
                    <li class="tree-menu">

                        child3b1-6
                        
                    </li>
                
                            </ul>
                        
                    </li>
                
                    <li class="tree-menu">

                        child3a2-5
                        
                    </li>
                
                            </ul>
                        
                    </li>
                
                            </ul>
                        
                    </li>
                
            </ul>
            
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $('.tree-menu').click(function () {
                    console.log("CALLED TOGGLE");
                    console.log(this);
                    $(this).children().toggle(1000);
                    return false;
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It's the version of Jquery. This is my import:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
```

Comment: Does anyone know whether or not using the normal jquery 3.3.1.min import will break anything in Bootstrap, since Bootstrap recommends 3.3.1.slim.min?